# How to obtain the memory space used by a jar during its execution

Tags: java, memory-management, jar

I've coded a java program that I can run using its resulting jar

```
java -jar foo.jar
```

I'm interested in obtaining the maximum memory size that my jar program request during its execution. Actually to do that I just look the memory management (like `htop`), but its not accurate.

I wonder if there is a special parameter that one set while launching the jar that allow to obtain such information at the end of the execution ?

Comment: Maybe get it from tasklist

Comment: I'm not aware of any approach that tracks the maximum heap used.  Most tools sample the JVM heap at regular intervals, but you might miss the max between samples.   If you are OK with that, VisualVM mentioned below is nice because it provides graphs of heap use.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried `visualVM`, its free and powerful tool to track the java performance application, it'll show you how much your JVM committed from the physical memory, also the total memory of the application that the current JVM running, and some features:

- Provide a CPU profiling.
- Provide all info about Threads.
- Provide the JVM Heap and the memory states.
- Provide Info about the GC activities.

Its come with the JDK package, so you don't have to install it, for more info check [this](http://visualvm.java.net/)

In your case you can do the following :

```
java -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8484 -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false -jar foo.jar
```

Open the `visualVM`,then select `File -> Add JMX connection`, then type your host ip and the port that you have been specified in the parameters "in our case its 8484" separated by :, eg `localhost:8484`, then you ready to go.

Comment: It's in no way specifically meant for Java EE (J2EE is an outdated term) applications. It attaches to any running JVM.

Comment: @Yuba it's possible to launch `virtual VM` on a jar file ? can you provide a sample of this ?